# Facebook OG:Image tag is not included in Opengraph in facebook debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have included the meta tags in the head section of the page

```
Og:url
Og:image
```

like this:

```
<title>villas</title>
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/v/i/villas/store_systeme144.html?NxTy=110464" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/dx577khz83dc.cloudfront.net/3330/280a471c-2661-4dd5-b8e5-6fc6876654fd.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/dx577khz83dc.cloudfront.net/3330/280a471c-2661-4dd5-b8e5-6fc6876654fd.jpg" />
```

> In the debugger -scraped URL - See exactly what our scraper sees for
>   your URL

Now when I follow the scraped URL - I can clearly see the image tag.
like this:

```
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags --><title>villas</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/v/i/villas/store_systeme144.html?NxTy=110464">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/dx577khz83dc.cloudfront.net/3330/280a471c-2661-4dd5-b8e5-6fc6876654fd.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/dx577khz83dc.cloudfront.net/3330/280a471c-2661-4dd5-b8e5-6fc6876654fd.jpg">
```

Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties.
All properties like

```
OG:url
OG:type
OG:title
OG:description
```

All are all correctly retrieved except
`OG:image`.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: When I load http://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/dx577khz83dc.cloudfront.net/3330/280a471c-2661-4dd5-b8e5-6fc6876654fd.jpg I get an error. A forbidden error.

Comment: Yes. I also checked that. but it is working fine with https.

Comment: So why are you specifying a url that doesn't work?

Comment: I also didn't know. I only get to know it now. ok removing and checking again.

Comment: removed the `og:image` tag, keeping the `og:image:secure_url`. but still doesn't work.

Comment: I get a forbidden error when I load https://louverturetravels.com/h/villas/dx577khz83dc.cloudfront.net/3330/280a471c-2661-4dd5-b8e5-6fc6876654fd.jpg also